# Is JpaRepository.save() suitable for entities with auto generated IDs if we want to UPSERT them?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm facing a problem with duplicate records in a MySQL database when I'm upserting using `JpaRepository.saveAll()` entities which are already present in the database. I want new entities to be inserted, existing ones to be updated(if there are changes to any of the properties), otherwise no action is expected.

The entity classes `id` property is annotated with `@GeneratedValue(GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and the `id` column in the corresponding table in MySQL has `auto-increment enabled`. I'm pointing that out because `JpaRepository.save()`, which is invoked for each entity in `saveAll()`, does a check by `id` if the entity is already present in the database.

1. Here is where in my opinion the contradiction between `save()`, when used for updating, and auto-generation of IDs occurs: You can't update existing records because all of the entities passed into `saveAll()` will have newly generated IDs and thus the check in `save()` will always say that they are not present in the database.

Is my logic correct?

2. The only solution to the problem that I can think of is to create a custom query that compares the records in the database with the newly passed entities by the values of another column whose values are unique. I can't compare them by id because I will encounter the same problem as in `save()`.

Is that good enough and are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you look at it, your are either wrong or right.

What you describe in terms of behaviour is correct: If you pass in an entity with id set to `null` to `save` you will always create a new row in the database and never perform an update. In that sense you are correct. That behaviour is independent of how the id gets generated for new entities.

But the id of an entity defines its identity. If two entities have the same id they represent the same row in the database thus the same logical entity and the behaviour of `save` is exactly that of an upsert. This is also independent of how the id gets generated for new entities.

If you want an upsert based on a different column (or columns) you need to write custom code, for example using an actual upsert statement in a query annotation. Alternatively you can try to load the entity by the columns in question and if you succeed set its values as desired and otherwise create a new entity and save that.

Comment: "If you want an upsert based on a different column (or columns)"
No, I want an upsert based on id, but I find that impossible if it is auto-generated(I think auto-generating the IDs is natural and I don't see a benefit to assigning them myself), am I wrong?  As far as I understand, when using save() in combination with auto-generated IDs  only INSERT behaviour is possible. That's why I'm forced to use another column for comparison

Comment: As described you'll see proper UPSERT behaviour with any ID generation strategy.

Comment: *edited previous comment* That's strange, because I think I'm doing everything correctly, but it doesn't work:
1) Create entities using constructor without "id" property (since I want it generated by MySQL)
2) Gather them in a collection and pass them to saveAll()
3) Duplicates are populated into the database :/

Comment: @SimeonYachev  if you can add some minimalistic example it will be clear.
repository.save() - will update the existing entities if you have set id for them before calling save(). If not it will generate new id.

Comment: "If you pass in an entity with id set to null to save you will always create a new row in the database and never perform an update. In that sense you are correct. That behaviour is independent of how the id gets generated for new entities."

Comment: @Lucia I didn't add an example because it's too trivial, imagine something like : `Collection<Entity> entities = List.of(new Entity(p1, p2, p3), new Entity(p1,p2,p3));
entityRepository.saveAll(entities);` The thing is that I don't want to add an id to the constructors, because that makes the auto-generation redundant, but using it seems like I can't use `saveAll()`

Comment: I atleast have not faced any issues as such. I can see that in the logs of JPA it correctly sends insert query for new entities and update for existing entities when calling saveAll() from JPA repo.
You can enable the hibernate logs or what ever you are using and check the generated queries.
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE